# How to calculate accuracy for K-means clustering model from "Within Set Sum of Squared Errors" value in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I am working with Spark and wondering how to obtain the accuracy value for the K-means clustering model created. While, checking the Spark - KMeansModel APIs, I found "ComputeCost" and that returns the "Within Set Sum of Squared Errors" value.

Is there a way to calculate accuracy of the model created from the "Within Set Sum of Squared Errors" value?

Or, is there any other option available in Spark to obtain it? Please advise me on this.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Accuracy is a useful metric in supervised learning, such as classification. However, in case of unsupervised learning (like KMeans), there is no accuracy (as there is no labeled data / gold standard you can evaluate against.

Assuming you are using Spark 2.3.0, you can use the ClusteringEvaluator for assessing the quality of your KMeansModel. You can find more information in the docs: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/evaluation/ClusteringEvaluator.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use pyspark to run K-Means clustering, getting "Within Set Sum of Squared Errors" is fairly straighforward:

```
#K-Means
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans

ClusterData=data.select("ID","features")

#Fitting
kmeans = KMeans().setK(10).setSeed(1)
model = kmeans.fit(ClusterData)

#Evaluation

wssse = model.computeCost(ClusterData)
print("Within Set Sum of Squared Errors = " + str(wssse))

#Results
centers = model.clusterCenters()
print("Cluster Centers: ")
for center in centers:
 print(center)
```

The cluster center information is another good indicator that could later be fed into a visualization tool.